# Where are the begin() and end() functions defined in C++?

Tags: c++, iterator

In cppreference.com, it states that the `begin()` and `end()` functions are defined in the header file `< iterator >`. But I still can use the `begin()` and `end()` functions without including the `< iterator >` header. I wonder why? Is it because I use;

```
using namespace std;
```

So it is included?

Comment: No, `using namespace xxx` doesn't include any header files. It only means that you can write `begin()` instead of `std::begin()`. The `<iterator> header must be included through some other header that you did include into your .cpp.

Comment: Unrelate to answer: Avoid writing `using namespace std;` in real code.

Comment: @MohitJain Why is that?

Comment: @SH.C Check [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: @MohitJain Oh, ok, thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read from notes on the [same page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin):

> In addition to being included in `<iterator>`, `std::begin` is guaranteed to become available if any of the following headers are included: `<array>`, `<deque>`, `<forward_list>`, `<list>`, `<map>`, `<regex>`, `<set>`, `<string>`, `<unordered_map>`, `<unordered_set>`, and `<vector>`.

Apart from these list of headers, `std::begin` may get included from some other header also.

Comment: Oh, ok, I didn't see that. That make so much more sense.

Answer (score 1):

No, `using namespace xxx` doesn't include any header files. It only means that you can write `begin()` instead of `std::begin()`. The `<iterator>` header must be included through some other header that you did include into your .cpp.